# Will these object keys always be in same order?

Tags: javascript, object, key

I am making multiple objects, then I am `JSON.stringify`ing them.  Then I am turning them into a hash.  I need all of the properties to be stringified in the same order so my hashes are consistent.  For example:

```
function createObj(index, value, key) {
    var obj = {
        value: value,
        index: index,
        key: key
    };

    return obj;
 };


console.log(JSON.stringify(createObj(1, 'blue', 'ABC')));   // =>  {"value":"blue","index":1,"key":"ABC"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(createObj(2, 'red', 'DEF')));    // =>  {"value":"red","index":2,"key":"DEF"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(createObj(3, 'green', 'GHI')));  // =>  {"value":"green","index":3,"key":"GHI"}
```

Can I always expect the keys to be stringified in the order that I have placed them on the object in my `createObj` function?  I do not add any more properties to the objects after they are created.

If I cannot guarantee this order, can you recommend a way to guarantee the order of the keys for this purpose?

**EDIT:** I realize that when iterating an object the order of the keys is not guaranteed (`for-in` and `Object.keys`) but would the order be guaranteed for `stringify`ing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Just push it to the array.

Comment: @NikolaLukic push it to what array?

Comment: The modern JavaScript standard provides more assurances about the behavior of property order than it used to, but to me it still seems really fragile to rely on it. However I understand (maybe) that it would be nice if stringifying an object that "looks" exactly like another object would give you exactly the same JSON serialization string.

Comment: For what purpose do you need to guarantee the order? I would imagine for unit testing you can use `JSON.parse()`  to check the validity of the returned object.

Comment: @Xeraqu I am turning the `stringified` object into a hash so I want to keep the key order consistent in the string

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON.stringify()` documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-json.stringify) do not indicate the order in which keys are stringified. While that order my very well be sequential for primitive types like `string`, `number`, and `boolean`, you can't really be sure for objects, functions, arrays, etc. Your best bet would likely be to implement your own version of `stringify` in order to be 100% certain of the output.